# Setting the Ruby on Rails application environment using Capistrano on Phusion Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, passenger, capistrano

I have 2 environments, *production* and *staging*, and I am using Capistrano with capistrano-ext gem.

When I deploy to *staging* using Capistrano and restart passenger, I would like the deployed application to run in *staging* however it runs in the default *production*

I tried setting:

```
set :rails_env, "staging"
```

in my deploy recipe, but this had no effect.

I am aware this can be done by setting a virtual host in Apache, but I am using shared hosting, so don't have access. My host offers this advice:

> add the following to environment.rb: ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'staging'

but this doesn't help me automate the process with Capistrano.

Comment: Is adding `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'staging'` itself works? If it works, then it's just a matter of writing a Capistrano recipe to automate that.

Comment: Have you tried asking your hosting company to change the environment for you? That is the best way to solve this. If they refuse to cooperate you can draw your conclusions about them.

Comment: @htanata - Yes that works, ill look into automating that from Capistrano, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a capistrano hook to create files on the server or symlink them in from e.g. `shared/` when deploying.

### For Rails 2.3:

On your web host, create the file `shared/preinitializer.rb`:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'staging'
```

Then add this to your `Capfile` (or possibly `config/deploy.rb` if you're using a newer version of capistrano with Rails 2.x:

```
after 'deploy:symlink', 'localize:copy_shared_configurations'
namespace :localize do
  desc 'copy shared configurations to current'
  task :copy_shared_configurations, :roles => [:app] do
    # I put database.yml here to keep deployed db credentials out of git
    %w[
      preinitializer.rb
    ].each do |f|
      run "ln -nsf #{shared_path}/#{f} #{current_path}/config/#{f}"
    end
  end
end
```

### For Rails 3

Due to the changes in Rails 3's initialization sequence, `config/preinitializer.rb` is not loaded until after `config/environment.rb` is loaded. So for Rails 3, you want to modify `config/environment.rb` only on the server. You could do this with a similar setup like Rails 2 above, but using a symlinked copy of `config/environment.rb`, and adding the step of deleting the existing file before trying to symlink.

Another option would be to overwrite the environment.rb on the server from capistrano. In your `config/deploy.rb`:

```
after 'deploy:symlink', 'localize:munge_environment'
namespace :localize do
  desc 'munge environment.rb to set staging environment'
  task :munge_environment, :roles => [:app] do
    new_env = "ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'staging'\n" + File.read(Rails.root.join('config', 'environment.rb'))
    put new_env, "#{current_path}/config/environment.rb"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 16):

What you are doing when you setting `:rails_env, "staging"` environment is setting the environment for the migration.  In other words, it's a environment that is only set when you're running capistrano.  If I understand you correctly, you want to change the environment when running your app, not deploying.

In order to answer your question, I'll need to know how you are launching (starting) your application.

If you're using Phusion Passenger, you'll [need to edit your RAILS_ENV for Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#rails_env)

Given that you're in a shared environment, you'll probably want to go with the .htaccess route.

Comment: I don't start it as such, phusion passenger handles that.

Comment: Ah, good to know.  You'll need to edit your RAILS_ENV for Passenger.  Read this:  http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#rails_env  Given that you're in a shared environment, you'll probably want to go with the .htaccess route.

Comment: Thanks cory, you want to add that as an answer please?

Comment: Hi Pingu, I moved my reply to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The right way to solve this is to set the Rails environment in your Passenger config.  Get your shared hosting provider to set this up for you.  In Apache it's done with RailsEnv directive.

If you REALLY can't do that, you could consider putting a TERRIBLE HACK like this at the top of your Rails pre-initializer (config/preinitializer):

```
forced_environment = './config/force_environment'
if File.exists?(forced_environment)
  ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = File.new(forced_environment).readline.chomp
end
```

...which will set the environment before loading Rails to the string in that config/forced_environment file.  For your stage server you could set 'stage' as the environment.

This is a terrible, terrible hack.  Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score -2):

What you need is the environment directive in your nginx configuration.
If you are using Apache, there should be a similar directive there. (should be easy to google)

```
server {
        listen                  80;
        passenger_enabled       on;
        rails_env               staging;
        server_name             foo.com;
        root                    /your/app/path;

}
```

You cannot toggle this with just capistrano.

Comment: Says he's using shared hosting. Cannot change it.

Comment: What's the point of set :rails_env in capistrano if it does nothing?

Comment: Using `set :rails_env` simply ensures that on tasks which require it there is a command prepended such as `RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} rake db:migrate`.

Comment: Should be made clear that this is not a valid answer for this question yet it was the answer in my non shared hosting situation.